# Can one-way communication be enabled in Office Communicator

Tags: office-communicator-2007, ms-office-communicator

Is there a way to send group IMs in office communicator without letting the recipients send replies back to the sender?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auditorium chat rooms? 
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/communicator-help/creating-and-managing-chat-rooms-HA010333635.aspx

Comment: exactly what i was looking for! thanks - im trying it out now!